# Algorithm to find the largest land-mass a city is connected to?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, geospatial, connectivity, gaps-and-islands

I have a black and white picture of the world map.

I convert the pixels to a grid of binary values (0 for water, and 1 for land) indexed by coordinates (i, j). Now, say I randomly pick a point on land, and this time it's somewhere in Texas, USA. I want to know the (i, j) coordinates of all the points I can travel to *without having to cross water*. In this case, it would be any (i, j) in all of North and South America (minus any surrounding islands).

(The motivation behind this is that I'm trying to implement an SIR infection model in c in parallel.)

Many thanks for your help.

**Edit:** I'd also be interested if there are any approximate methods (I'm not overly fussed if some tiny offshore islands were included by mistake.), perhaps by a meshing method like quadtrees? Thanks again.

Comment: Try a [flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill).

Comment: It seems like a simple flood-fill algorithm would do the trick.  There's dozens of implementations you could choose from.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for a [flood fill algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill). It can be done recursively, or manually maintaining a stack, or using a queue.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, I took a look at the algorithm, but from what I gather it's essentially doing a pixel-by-pixel examination, which seems slow.

Is there not an algorithm based on a mesh approach such as via quadtrees if I can tolerate some margin of error (i.e. not too fussed if some tiny offshore islands are included)?

Comment: Have you actually tried whether it's fast enough? This only inspects each pixel at most once, so it's linear in the number of pixels. It can't be done more efficiently, since you asked to have the coordinates of _all_ the points you can travel to, which is also linear in the number of pixels (in the general case). If you need to do lots of these lookups, you can preprocess your map into connected components and answer lookups in constant time.

Comment: Thanks again. Is there a parallel implementation that you know of? Either via MPI or OpenMP (or both) would be fine.

Thanks.